# Facebook API - Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 601: Parser error: unexpected ')' at position 37

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

I have a FB app script and im trying to make it work but I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 601: Parser error: unexpected ')' at position 37. thrown 
>   in /home/altin/public_html/apps/empower/empowermix/base_facebook.php on line 658

Here is the part of the script where I get the error:

```
$friendsLists = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
  foreach ($friendsLists as $friends) 
  {
   $ile=count($friends);
  }

$zapytanie=" (uid=".$friends[0]['id'].") ";
  for($i=1;$i<$ile;$i++)
  {
    $zapytanie.=" or (uid=".$friends[$i]['id'].") ";
  }

**$znajomi = $facebook->api(array("method"=> "fql.query", "query"=> "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE ".$zapytanie." AND page_id='".$page_id."'")); //friends w fanpage**

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM '".$przedrostek_tab."ludzie' WHERE 'uid'=".$user_info['id']);
$czy_jest=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
foreach($znajomi as $k => $w)
      {$znajomi_weryfikacja[$k]=$w['uid'];}
if($znajomi_weryfikacja)
  {$znajomi_weryfikacja=( array_diff($znajomi_weryfikacja, explode("|",$czy_jest['znajomi_start'])));
  if($czy_jest[0])
    {foreach($znajomi_weryfikacja as $k => $w)
      {$zaproszeni_znajomi.=$w.'|';}
    mysql_query("UPDATE '".$przedrostek_tab."ludzie' SET 'zaproszeni_znajomi' = '$zaproszeni_znajomi' WHERE 'uid' =".$user_info['id']);}
  }
```

Can anyone help suggest a solution? Maybe some of you may have faced similar problems before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have severe issues with your code handling Graph API response and construction of FQL query:

1. `$facebook->api('/me/friends')` returns associative array consisting of `data` (which contain friends details) and `paging`. (and just to be clear on naming this isn't friendlists but list of user's friends).
2. Error you get from API related to the fact that your query contain `(uid=)` in `WHERE` clause.

You can simply fix your loops:

```
$friendsList = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
$friends = $friendsList['data'];
$ile=count($friends);

$zapytanie=" (uid=".$friends[0]['id'].") ";
for($i=1;$i<$ile;$i++){
  $zapytanie.=" or (uid=".$friends[$i]['id'].") ";
}
// ...
```

Actually there is couple of things that you should learn about FQL and Graph API:

**You better retrieve only needed data and use `IN` instead of multiple `OR`**

```
$response = $facebook->api('/me/friends?fields=id');
$friends = $response['data'];
$uids = array();

foreach ($friends as $friend)
  $uids[] = $friend['id'];

$zapytanie = 'uid IN ('. implode(',', $uids) .')';
// ...
```

**Also you may do this all in single FQL query**

```
$fql = <<FQL
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = {$page_id} AND uid IN (
  SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
)
FQL;
```